# Some pages won't load in edit page sections

Tags: wordpress

So basically I'm stuck with this screen on some of my pages and they never load up. I'm using Avada theme and fusion builder. What could cause this problem because it's appearing only when I try to edit some pages and others I can edit normally

[image]

On the pages that won't load this appears in the console

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to look in the Javascript Console if there are errors logged?

Comment: You can look at the edited answer

Comment: Ok, error 500: so you have to check the PHP errors. I suggest you to enable [WP_DEBUG](https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG)

Comment: Great, that solved the problem of loading pages but once it's been loaded nothing appears in the edit section, just as it's a new page. However when I view the page everything appears normal

Comment: Ok I think it's a problem with fusion builder since its normally shown in default builder.